# Question mark or period?

Tags: punctuation, periods, question-mark

Is this sentence a question or a statement (or other). It ends with a question, so I used a question mark. (Just ignore the tech jargon.)

> I get that this should show me the PID of the SIGTERMing process and I successfully
>   compiled it, but how do I use it?

**Edit:** Another question, should it be written as (which is correct and which is clearer?)

> I get that this should show me the PID of the SIGTERMing process and successfully
>   compiled it, but how do I use it?

Comment: You correctly used the question mark in that sentence, but the first sentence in your question should also end with a question mark instead of a period!

Comment: The second sentence seems ambiguous. It's unclear whether *this* or *I* compiled it.

Comment: The interrogative independent clause is incorrectly tagged on to a nice statement. Use separate sentences for the sake of semantics. I know, don't worry about starting a sentence with a conjunction, haha. "I get that (phrase) and I successfully compiled it. But how do I use it?"

Comment: Seeing how you don't even end an actual question with a question mark ("Is this sentence a question or a statement (or other)."), I would say you should go ahead and use periods everywhere. Seriously though, I would really like to know what the "or other" part is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a question with some preamble.  I welcome preamble in order to set some context to the question.

To answer the second question, you could at least change "get" with "understand".

Comment: I think you could use either sentence and the "I" is optional, but it probably would be better grammar to use "understand" instead of "get" just to make things clear because I assume you mean understand rather than get which is more idiomatic.

Comment: @Soccem I don't quite get your first sentence (but agree with your second).